# Why is the BroadcastReceiver called multiple times?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My OnReceive() of the BroadcastReceiver gets called like every time I open the app, although the alarm is only fired once at 03.00 AM.

Im logging the time, where the onReceive() was last called, so I'm pretty sure the onReceive() is somewhat broken. Also it seems the onReceive() code is only executed once I actually start the app, and not just when the app is closed (and the actual code execution SHOULD happen)

MonthManager.java

```java
public class MonthManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("BISASAM","triggered");
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.sharedPrefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editPrefs = preferences.edit();
        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMANY);
        Date dat = new Date();
        Log.d("TRIGGERDATE",date.format(dat));
        editPrefs.putString("REC", "Receiver called "+date.format(dat));
        editPrefs.commit();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```java
public static final String alarm = "com.example.aufgaben_planer.alarm";
private void registerMyAlarmBroadcast()
    {
        createPendingIntent();
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(alarm),0));
        alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(alarm),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
        alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(alarm),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(this,MonthManager.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(this,MonthManager.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
        registerAlarmAt(3,0,0);
    }
    private void registerAlarmAt(int hour, int min, int sec){
        timingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        timingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour); // At the hour you want to fire the alarm
        timingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min); // alarm minute
        timingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec); // and alarm second
        long intendedTime = timingCal.getTimeInMillis();
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
    private void createPendingIntent(){
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MonthManager.class);
        alarmIntent.setAction(alarm);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, alarmIntent,0 );
    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application> ...
        <receiver android:name=".MonthManager">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.aufgaben_planer.alarm"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

Another note that might (or might not) be important: 
I never unregister the receiver (doesnt make sense to me, because I declare it in the Manifest)

Comment: Check you are not sending the broadcast yourself in the code somewhere with the action "com.example.aufgaben_planer.alarm". Most probably in onResume().

Comment: just searched through the whole code, I'm never sending any broadcast myself, besides with the help of the AlarmManager